# SharePoint online page banner image is creating irregularly in different site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, image-display

SharePoint online page banner image is creating under site assets library directly.

Say: `site assets --> image.png`

Where as in another site collection image is uploaded as say:

`site assets --> site pages --> page name --> image.png`

Can any one help if there are any settings to be changed for news article/page creation.

Comment: Are you trying to add banner image in both the cases OR banner image in one site and image in web parts (like image, text, etc.) in second site? Are you following same steps for both the sites, manually uploading banner images or selecting images from Stock images/Web search?